# How to save an Arduino code ".ino extension" from my webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arduino

I have created a webpage to write an Arduino code and after that i would like to save the code on the pc, so i use new Blob to save the file and the extension is .ino,, but when i go to the created file i got these messages

> Could not create the sketch
>
> Failed to open sketch: 'direction for the file'

I would like to know How to save .ino file

```
var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([encodeURIComponent(arduinoSource)], {type:'data:text/ino;charset=utf-8,'});
var datenow = Date.now();
var fileNameToSaveAs = "arduino_code" +datenow+ ".ino";
  saveAs(textToSaveAsBlob, fileNameToSaveAs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data URIs inside anchor element to generate your download. Browser support varies though, check out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support) description.

For example, the following function takes in your filename and code and generates a download. The way it works is that it creates an anchor element in your DOM, defines charset and content type of your file, appends your code, launches a click event on the anchor element to generate download and then destroys the element.

```
function download(filename, code) {
      var element = document.createElement('a');
      element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(code));
      element.setAttribute('download', filename);
      element.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(element);
      element.click();
      document.body.removeChild(element);
 }
```

I have written the following snippet to generate your required functionality, added a bit of Arduino style CSS as well. Hope it helps!

```js
function download(filename, code) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(code));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);
  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

var dateNow = Date.now();
var fileName = 'ArduinoCode';
document.getElementById("arduino-file-name").innerHTML = fileName;


document.getElementById("download-code").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var arduinoCode = document.getElementById("arduino-code").value;
  var fileNameFull = fileName + "-" + dateNow + ".ino";
  download(fileNameFull, arduinoCode);
}, false);
```

```css
.arduino-menu-bar {
  background-color: #006468;
  padding: 10px;
}

.arduino-menu-bar--footer {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #4db7bb;
}

#download-code {
  border: none;
  color: #4db7bb;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#download-code:hover {
  color: #7ac4c7;
}

.arduino-files-bar {
  background-color: #4db7bb;
  padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}

.open-file-title {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #006468;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#arduino-code {
  font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Code&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css">

<div class="arduino-code-container">
  <div class="arduino-menu-bar">
    <i id="download-code" class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="arduino-files-bar">
    <div id="arduino-file-name" class="open-file-title"></div>
  </div>
  <textarea id="arduino-code">
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
  </textarea>
  <div class="arduino-menu-bar arduino-menu-bar--footer"></div>
</div>
```